# Banco de Dados Parou

Tags: android

Estou com uma aplicação que estou executando direto no celular Android, e ele gera uma mensagem de erro no LogCat

```
12-05 15:55:18.043: D/ActivityThread(27221): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
12-05 15:55:18.043: D/ActivityThread(27221): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
12-05 15:55:18.043: D/ActivityThread(27221): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
12-05 15:55:18.173: E/SQLiteLog(27221): (1) no such table: carro
12-05 15:55:18.173: E/livro(27221): Erro ao buscar os carros: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: carro (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, nome, placa, ano FROM carro
12-05 15:55:18.173: D/AndroidRuntime(27221): Shutting down VM
12-05 15:55:18.173: W/dalvikvm(27221): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f10438)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bancodedados/com.example.bancodedados.CadastroCarros}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at com.example.bancodedados.RepositorioCarro.listarCarros(RepositorioCarro.java:155)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at com.example.bancodedados.CadastroCarros.atualizarLista(CadastroCarros.java:36)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at com.example.bancodedados.CadastroCarros.onCreate(CadastroCarros.java:30)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
12-05 15:55:18.183: E/AndroidRuntime(27221):     ... 11 more
12-05 15:55:31.523: I/Process(27221): Sending signal. PID: 27221 SIG: 9
12-05 15:56:27.283: I/Process(27836): Sending signal. PID: 27836 SIG: 9
```

a mensagem que aparece no celular é que `Bando de Dados Parou`

minha classe CadastroCarro

```
package com.example.bancodedados;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.bancodedados.model.Carro;
import com.example.bancodedados.model.Carro.Carros;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class CadastroCarros extends ListActivity {

    protected static final int INSERIR_EDITAR = 1;
    protected static final int BUSCAR = 2;

    public static RepositorioCarro repositorio;

    private List<Carro> carros;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        repositorio = new RepositorioCarro(this);
        atualizarLista();
    }


    protected void atualizarLista() {
        // Pega a lista de carros e exibe na tela
        carros = repositorio.listarCarros();

        //Adaptador de lista customizado para cada linha de um carro
        // Fonte está na biblioteca LivroAndroidCap14-BancoDados-Library
        setListAdapter(new CarroListAdapter(this, carros));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_cadastro_carros, menu);
        menu.add(0, INSERIR_EDITAR, 0, "Inserir Novo").setIcon(R.drawable.novo);
        menu.add(0, BUSCAR, 0, "Buscar").setIcon(R.drawable.pesquisar);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        // Clicou no menu
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_editar:
            // Abre a tela com o formulário para adicionar
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, EditarCarro.class), INSERIR_EDITAR);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_buscar:
            // Abre a tela para buscar o carro pelo nome
            startActivity(new Intent(this, BuscarCarro.class));
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int posicao, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, posicao, id);
        editarCarro(posicao);
    }

    // Recupera o id do carro, e abre a tela de edição
    protected void editarCarro(int posicao) {
        // Usuário clicou em algum carro da lista
        // Recupera o carro selecionado
        Carro carro = carros.get(posicao);
        // Cria a intent para abrir a tela de editar
        Intent it = new Intent(this, EditarCarro.class);
        // Passa o id do carro como parâmetro
        it.putExtra(Carros._ID, carro.id);
        // Abre a tela de edição
        startActivityForResult(it, INSERIR_EDITAR);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int codigo, int codigoRetorno, Intent it) {
        super.onActivityResult(codigo, codigoRetorno, it);

        // Quando a activity EditarCarro retornar, seja se foi para adicionar vamos atualizar a lista
        if (codigoRetorno == RESULT_OK) {
            // atualiza a lista na tela
            atualizarLista();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Fecha o banco
        repositorio.fechar();
    }

}
```

eu entendi que ele está dizendo que não encontrou essa classe acima, mas ela existe.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bancodedados"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="CadastroCarros">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.bancodedados.EditarCarro" android:label="EditarCarro"/>
        <activity android:name="com.example.bancodedados.BuscarCarro" android:label="BuscarCarro"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ele está dizendo que não consegue encontrar a tabela "carro" . Tente verificar a classe ao qual você definiu, pois pode ser algo bobo como por exemplo uma vírgula, ou parêntese.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na tabela **carro**, que não existe. Veja se o nome da tabela não é **carros**. Com o '***s***' no final.